# How to activate Swiper Slider on dynamically loaded HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, swiper.js

How to activate Swiper Slider on dynamically loaded HTML which is loaded via AJAX after submitting the form?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const swiper = new Swiper('.worksSlider', {
    // Optional parameters
    loop: true,
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/7.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="worksSlider swiper-slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 1
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code does not matches your question. When AJAX responds with a HTML payload, init Swiper on the desired element. `window.onload` is not an AJAX form submit callback clearly.